# How to compile the linux without any audio codecs?

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I want "no audio" functionality in an embedded system. So, any idea about how to configure kernel without any audio?

Thanks.

Comment: So did you actually ever start `make menuconfig`?

Comment: I was about to ask about that as well. You can disable a *load* of stuff, or make them modules from menuconfig

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `make menuconfig` to find the name of the subsystem (in this case `CONFIG_SOUND`).
2. Create a [kernel config fragment](https://elinux.org/images/3/39/Managing-Linux-Kernel-Configurations-with-Config-Fragments-Darren-Hart-VMware.pdf) containing:

```
CONFIG_SOUND=n
```

3. Setup your configuration file with both the default config and the fragment:

```
make defconfig <NAME_OF_FRAGMENT>
```

Answer (score -1):

From `make menuconfig`, disable `Device Drivers` -> `Sound card support`, or if you're editing the `.config` file, prepend `CONFIG_SOUND` with a `#`.

Comment: *"if you're editing the .config file..."* -- Bad advice.